# How to load data to generate data visualizations through Hugo shortcodes?

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts, hugo, hugo-shortcode

[Hugo native shortcodes](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/) don't manage data visualizations. However, I found a Hugo theme ([DoIt](https://hugodoit.pages.dev/)) that handles data visualizations [through shortcodes with ECharts](https://hugodoit.pages.dev/theme-documentation-extended-shortcodes/#echarts). With this theme, ECharts option just has to be inserted in JSON, YAML or TOML format in the ECharts shortcode.

Here is an example:

```
{{< echarts >}}
{
"xAxis": {
    "type": "category",
    "boundaryGap": false,
    "data": ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "type": "value"
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
      "type": "line",
      "areaStyle": {}
    }
  ]
}
{{< /echarts >}}
```

**Instead of having the data directly within the shortcode, how could I load it from a CSV or a JSON file?**

Data in the mentioned example:

```
|----------+-------|
| category | value |
|----------+-------|
| Mon      |   820 |
| Tue      |   932 |
| Wed      |   901 |
| Thu      |   934 |
| Fri      |  1290 |
| Sat      |  1330 |
| Sun      |  1320 |
|----------+-------|
```

`input.csv`:

```
category,value
Mon,820
Tue,932
Wed,901
Thu,934
Fri,1290
Sat,1330
Sun,1320
```

`input.json`:

```
[
  {
    "category": "Mon",
    "value": 820
  },
  {
    "category": "Tue",
    "value": 932
  },
  {
    "category": "Wed",
    "value": 901
  },
  {
    "category": "Thu",
    "value": 934
  },
  {
    "category": "Fri",
    "value": 1290
  },
  {
    "category": "Sat",
    "value": 1330
  },
  {
    "category": "Sun",
    "value": 1320
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [os.Readfile](https://gohugo.io/functions/os/readfile/)

Create layouts/shortcodes/load_file.html:

```
{{ readFile (.Get "file_name") }}
```

Then, add the following to your page:

```
{{< echarts >}}
{{< load_file file_name="path/to/input.json" >}}
{{< /echarts >}}
```

Comment: How does this work if I have multiple datasets to load for multiple Dataviz on a page?

Comment: it should work. Just pass different files
{{< echarts >}}
{{< load_file file_name="path/to/input.json" >}}
{{< /echarts >}}
{{< echarts >}}
{{< load_file file_name="path/to/input2.json" >}}
{{< /echarts >}}

Comment: But then, what would be the two different names of these two different variables?

Comment: The shortcode get loaded twice. The first time with $file_name="path/to/input.json", the second time with $file_name="path/to/input2.json". That's the power of shortcodes, you can repeat something with a few parameters tweaked.